# SSRS help on expresson'Please how can i put this expression in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services

Please how can i put this expression in SSRS expression
count(SectionActive)
From ADF_path
where SectionActive = 'Y'
any help would be really apricated
i hasve tried this and  =Count(Fields!EventActive.Value ='Y')  it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Tyr something like

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!EventActive.Value ='Y', 1, 0))
```

All we are doing here is looking at each row, if EventActve = "Y" then return 1 else return 0 and then summing the results.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so please mark the answer as accepted